# My app keeps telling me that I am trying to re-render too many times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a small app that lets a user see a game.  If they log in, they can see the game editor.

So when the app first loads, it just shows them the game window.

However, when they log in, I want to show them the game editor.

So when it first loads, and the user is not logged in, it does show the game.

However, if I try to log in, I am getting error like this in browser:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

It tells me on this line:

```js
setLoginStatus(true);
```

Here is my app:

```
const Header = () => {

    const [showGameEditWindow, setGameEditWindow] = useState(false);
    const [showGame, setGame] = useState(true);
    const [loggedInStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);

    console.log("loggedInStatus: ", loggedInStatus);
    console.log("showGameEditWindow: ", showGameEditWindow);

    if (loggedInStatus) {
        setGame(false);
        setGameEditWindow(true);
    }
    
    //this doesn't run if user is already logged in
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            setLoginStatus(true);
        } else {
            setLoginStatus(false);
        }
    })
    
    const handleTableClick = useCallback(e => { setGame(true) || setGameEditWindow(false) }, []);
    const handleGameEditorClick = useCallback(e => { setGame(false) || setGameEditWindow(true) }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    {<RenderLoginLink
                        onClick={handleLoginClick}
                        loggedInStatus={loggedInStatus}
                        returnToMain={handleTableClick}
                        adminTable={handleGameEditorClick}
                    />}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    {showGame && <Game />}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {showGameEditWindow && <GameEditor onClick={handleGameEditorClick} />}
                </div>
                <div id="portal-root"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
  
  );
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `if (loggedInStatus)..setGame` block is just hanging out in the body of your component, it runs on every rerender, which triggers another render and you're stuck in the loop you're in.  You want to use the `useEffect` hook which watches for changes on variables you supply (dependencies) and then runs code when those change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loggedInStatus) {
    setGame(false);
    setGameEditWindow(true);
  }
}, [loggedInStatus]);
```

The code inside will only run when `loggedInStatus` changes, which will solve your too many re-renders problem.

Comment: What is the difference between putting `loggedInStatus` or ` showGameEditWindow showGame` in the useEffect method? thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell that is an array of dependencies.  When one of those changes, the code inside `useEffect` will run.  Since you're wanting to watch to see if `loggedInStatus` has changed, it makes sense to use that as your dependency.  Using `[showGameEditWindow, showGame]` would only run when those two variables change.  Based on your code, that will never happen so your code inside `useEffect` won't run when `loggedInStatus` changes (which I assume is your desired result).

Answer (score 3):

move this to useEffect:

```
ussEffect(()=>{
if (loggedInStatus) {
    setGame(false);
    setGameEditWindow(true);
}
},[showGameEditWindow showGame])
```

Comment: thanks, in my code where does that `useEffect` go?  At the end?

Comment: you have to replace the if statement with this useEffect (above the return section)